# Taking User Input for an Array

Tags: java, arrays

A link to the assignment: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/utlLG.png

I'm having a bit of trouble discerning how to take a series of numbers and apply them to an array without a loop. Not only that, but I'm having a bit of trouble comparing them. What I have written so far is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lottery {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 int userInputs[] = new int[5];
 int lotteryNumbers [] = new int[5];
 int matchedNumbers =0;
 char repeatLottery = '\0';


    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter your 5 single-digit lottery numbers.\n (Use the spacebar to separate digits): ");
            for(int i = 0; i <5; i++ )
            userInputs[i] = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Your inputs: ");
            printArray(userInputs);

        System.out.println("\nLottery Numbers: ");
        readIn(lotteryNumbers);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.print(lotteryNumbers[i] + " ");
        }

        matchedNumbers = compareArr(userInputs, lotteryNumbers);

        System.out.println("\n\nYou matched " + matchedNumbers + " numbers");



        System.out.println("\nDo you wish to play again?(Enter Y or N): ");
         repeatLottery = in.next().charAt(0);
    }
    while (repeatLottery == 'Y' || repeatLottery == 'y');

}
public static void printArray(int arr[]){

    int n = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static void readIn(int[] List) {
    for(int j=0; j<List.length; j++) {
        List[j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
    }
}

public static int compareArr (int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    int same = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= list1.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= list2.length-1; j++) {
            if (list1[i] == list2[j]) {
                same++;


            }

        }
    }
    return same;
}
```

}

As you'll notice, I commented out the input line because I'm not quite sure how to handle it. If I have them in an array, I should be able to compare them fairly easily I think. This is our first assignment handling arrays, and I think it seems a bit in-depth for only having one class-period on it; So, please forgive my ignorance. :P

Edit:

I added a new method at the end to compare the digits, but the problem is it compares them in-general and not from position to position. That seems to be the major issue now.

Comment: The commented out portion should already be the correct way to write it? Then loop through and compare the two arrays.

Comment: So you're not allowed to use a for loop to set the values of the array? Is that the case? It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

your question isn't 100% clear but i will try my best.
1- i don't see any problems with reading input from user

```
int[] userInput = new int[5]; // maybe here you had a mistake
int[] lotterryArray = new int[5]; // and here you were declaring your arrays in a wrong way
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(system.in);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
 userInput[i] = scanner.nextInt();
} // this will populate your array try to print it to make sure
```

Edit : important in the link you shared about the assignment the compare need to check the value and location so if there are two 5 one in input one in loterry array  they need to be in the same location check the assignment again

```
// to compare
int result = 0 ; // this will be the number of matched digits
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
{
   if ( userInput[i] == loterryArray[i] )
       result++
}
// in this comparsion if the digits are equale in value and location result will be incremented
```

Comment: The comparison worked. I created an int method that returned the result. Thank you!

Comment: Edit : important,,,,,, in the link you shared about the assignment the compare need to check the value and location so if there are two 5 one in input one in loterry array they need to be in the same location check the assignment again